# How can I get newly created node of a certain type?

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

I understand I could use `hook_nodeapi('insert')` in Drupal 6 ([Drupal hook fired after node created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675091/drupal-hook-fired-after-node-created)), but this seems to have changed in Drupal 7. What would the equivalent of that in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent of `hook_nodeapi('insert')` in Drupal 7 is [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7).

```
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  db_insert('mytable')
    ->fields(array(
    'nid' => $node->nid, 
    'extra' => $node->extra,
  ))
    ->execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, meanwhile I found an actual copy paste implementation as well here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/how-to-set-url-alias-automatically-for-a-content-type-without-using-pathauto-whi

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, several hooks that previously allowed modules to do a group of related operations, with a $op argument, were split into individual hooks for each operation.

See [node.api.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/7).