# How to set a custom URL for a node without pathauto?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a content type that requires me to assemble a URL from several sources - the node title, a taxonomy value, and some fields of a product that are referenced from a product display that this content type references.  So:

mynode type
  - title
  - taxonomy value
  - entity ref -> product display -> product field

The entity ref can have one or more products, so there is some logic I need to crunch to assemble the right URL.  I didn't have luck doing this through pathauto, so it looks like I need to handle this on hook_node_presave(), which does set my alias, but I get a 404 on that alias, so it seems I'm missing a step.

My code is:

```
mymodule_node_presave($node) {
    if (empty($node->path['alias'])) {
        $node->path['alias'] = _some_fx_that_figures_out_url();
        $node->path['pid'] = 0;  
        $node->path['language'] = LANGUAGE_NONE;  
    }
}
```

I guess I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a duplicate of [this issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/how-to-set-url-alias-automatically-for-a-content-type-without-using-pathauto-wh)

Try using hook_node_insert($node) for new content and/or hook_node_update($node) for existing content:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'mytype') {
    $node->path['alias'] = _some_awesome_pattern_maker($node);
  }
}

function mymodule_node_update($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'mytype') {
    $node->path['alias'] = _some_awesome_pattern_maker($node);
  }
}

_some_awesome_pattern_maker($node) {
  // massage node and return string
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I needed to do the same thing WITH Pathauto, like:
`function mymodule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  if (isset($context['data']['node']) && $context['data']['node']->type == 'my_content_type') {
    $node = $context['data']['node'];
    $alias = _awesome_alias_maker($node);
  }
}`

Comment: That doesn't work.  My alias does display in my node edit page, but I get a 404.  When I look at my node in devel, I don't have an alias value set, but I do have a pid value set.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your pattern-maker function returns?  I just tried `hook_node_presave($node)` on my local dev box and it seemed to behave as expected, and I did not get a 404 trying the url.
Does there happen to be anything helpful in the logs regarding the 404? Perhaps the symptom is misleading.

Comment: It looks like I wasn't setting the language val.  When I set it in the DB, it works.  Investigating further...

Comment: I can't seem to get the language value set in my path array.  It makes the entry into the aliases table, but doesn't set the language.  When I go set the language (in my case, 'und') by hand, it works.  I need to figure out why the language val isn't being set in the aliases table.